# How would I read this json string with the org.json API

Tags: java, json

so i have the following json string

```
{"Composition": {
    "Ice": 0.818085,
    "Rock": 0.165417,
    "Metal": 0.016499
  }
}
```

I want this to be read and passed to a new instance of a class but I dont see how I can read it when i dont know the name.

I've tried reading it as an Array which didnt work and tried to read it out via the name but thats not a proper solution for me.

I need it so that whenever the string keyword changes it still gets it so for example when 'Ice' changes to 'Gas' that I dont have to manual tell it to search for gas  I want a simple solution which reads out all of the Composition ***valuesname + the double value***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, [JSONObject](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html) has some methods that might fit your case, they are:

- `keys()`
- `keySet()`
- `names()`
- `getNames()`

They all return all the names of the fields in the JSONObject, so you can take the JSONObject of "composition" and get the name of the fields with one of those methods, then get all the values using those keys.

Answer (score -1):

On the [GitHub Page](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) of org.json there is a big fat List in the [README.md](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/README.md) with all possible usages of this API.

One of them reads:

> JSONObject.java: The JSONObject can parse text from a String or a JSONTokener to produce a map-like object.

Sounds for me exactly what you want.